# I went window-shopping and I was window-shopping

Tags: meaning, word-usage, expressions

Can you tell me about 2 sentences below. I don't know which one is make sense or both of them are right?

1. I went window-shopping.
2. I was window-shopping.

Comment: (a) _window-shop_ is a compound verb [[Collins](https://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/window-shop)]. So (2) is just the same construction as 'I was sleeping / talking / shopping ...'.  The past continuous. // (b) There is the verb + _ing_-form construction that Cobuild call a 'phase-' construction: _She goes dancing. He has gone fishing. He sat knitting. He came fishing with us. She went shopping._ This is even sometimes called the 'go shopping' construction. This explains the first example.

Comment: There is also the difference between past and past continuous to consider, which I took to be the question.

Answer (score 0):

We use *go + Ving* when we mean *to move somewhere in order to do something*. In this case you went (let's say to the shopping mall) to window-shop. Window-shopping was the reason for going there.

But *I was window-shopping* means that this activity was continuous. There is nothing about moving IN ORDER to do something.

Compare:

1. I went skiing last winter (I did this activity then; I went to the mountains to practice skiing).
2. I was skiing when the heavy snowfall began. (I was in the middle of skiing when it started snowing heavily).